# Post hoc comparisons for three-way interaction effect for linear mixed models (lme4)

Tags: r, lme4, posthoc

I want to conduct post hoc comparisons for a model with a three-way interaction:

```
FullModel <- lmer(CIVADmc ~ 1 + Factor1 * Factor2 * Factor3 + (1|ID) + (1 | Item), data=EXP3)
```

I tried the following, but this does not work.

```
summary(glht(FullModel, linfct = mcp(Factor1*Factor2*Factor3 = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm”))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Katharina and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a reproducible example (with data) of your problem so people can help you! Also, what error messages do you get?

Comment: For some pointers in creating a reproducible example, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example